# Pay API permission denied

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts, google-play-developer-api

I'd like to validate my in-app purchases.

I'm using [this receipt validator](https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator) which by looking at the source code is calling `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/<appId>/purchases/products/<productId>/tokens/<token>`, here's my code basically copied from the readme

```
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
$googleClient->setScopes([Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
$googleClient->setApplicationName('my project name');
$googleClient->setAuthConfig('files/googleauthconfig.json');

$validator = new Validator(new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($googleClient));

try {
  $response = $validator->setPackageName('my.app.id')
          ->setProductId('my.product.id')
          ->setPurchaseToken('token i got from my app when purchasing')
          ->validatePurchase();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
  exit;
}

var_dump($response);
exit;
```

I've hardcoded a lot of stuff because I'm just trying to get it to work at this point. `googleauthconfig.json` is the JSON file dev console gave me for my service account which contains a bunch of IDs for the account as well as a private key. I went in my play console and made my service account an administrator and then waited about 24 hours as suggested in other questions for the same problem. I've configured my products, which are consumable and active and I successfully purchase them through my signed release app with the test credit card.

The error I keep getting is

> The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.

Comment: Whats Validator? can you put the code for that.  You should be running everything though an android Google_Service_AndroidPublisher service.

Comment: @DaImTo I linked to the repo, it's some kind of wrapper that I don't really need but used it anyway https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator/blob/master/src/GooglePlay/Validator.php

Comment: This is my sample code for V2 i haven't generated the code for v3 yet https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%20Play%20Developer%20API/v2

Comment: @DaImTo I copied the code twice the variable is correct I'm sorry that's on me, there is no error in the code, I'm successfully getting a response from google.

Comment: I am out of ideas then you might want to wait see if anyone else has an any ideas.   Or keep trying i seam to remember a delay in the service account permissions kicking in.  Beyond that i would try using it without your validator to ensure its not that causing your issues.

Answer (score 2):

> The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.

Means exactly that the user you are authenticating with does not have the permissions to do what you are trying to do.  You are using a service account.  A service account is not you.  Service accounts are preauthorized.

Go over to google pay probably the admin section take the Service account email address and grant it permissions to access the data. You probably do this like you would any other user.

As mentioned in the comment it can take time normally under an hour for a service account to kick in.  After you grant it access.

### possible code error.

I think you should try the pure code rather that using your validator to ensure that its not thats the problem.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
$client->setApplicationName('my project name');
$client->setAuthConfig('files/googleauthconfig.json');    
$service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);   

try {

  $response = $service->purchases_products->get(package_name, product_id, purchase_token);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
  exit;
}

var_dump($response);
exit;
```

Comment: Isn't this what I did by making my service account an administrator in my play console?

Comment: Yes it should be but apparently you didnt do it correctly go back and double check once you have set that up correctly it will work.

Comment: How can I not do that correctly? It's pretty simple, I can provide screenshots if necessary..

Comment: I cant tell you that all i can tell you is the error message you are getting says that the service account doesnt have permissions to access the data you are trying ot access. there for you have not granted it permissions properly.  The scope looks correct.

Comment: https://i.snag.gy/KJur1c.jpg I honestly don't see what I can do wrong here, the account is the same as in the json file, I triple-checked.

Comment: Why are only some of them blue?

Comment: Because apparently you can't be an administrator and disable those, if I change the role to something else then I can disable them but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Its been a while since i have set this up and i no longer have access to that account.  I think this is what i followed https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started  Your right it looks right.

Comment: It may have been a typo but i still think you should try without your validator and just pure code.

Comment: That is not valid code, the service does not have such methods. Still I replaced it with the corresponding service code which is `$service->purchases_products->get(...)` and the result is the same, as expected

Comment: I just added the answer, in case you are curious. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, oddly enough, as suggested in other answers as well, I just needed to wait in my case about 30 hours before the permission changes took effect.

Comment: I am glad i was able to help you.  Good luck with your project.